# Self Join with Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join, correlated-subquery

I need to find an employee with a salary greater than their Manager. For this, I used to following query and it works;

```
    SELECT 
        e1.EmpID
        ,e1.EmpName
        ,e1.EmpSalary
        ,e1.ManagerID
    FROM empsalary e
    INNER JOIN empsalary e1 ON e.EmpID = e1.ManagerID
    WHERE e1.EmpSalary > e.EmpSalary
```

But following one is not working. I want to know why it is not? Why it's result is null? What should be correct format?

```
SELECT * 
FROM empsalary as e
WHERE e.empsalary=(
                   SELECT e1.empsalary 
                   FROM empsalary as e1 
                   WHERE e.EmpID = e1.ManagerID 
                   AND e1.EmpSalary > e.EmpSalary)
```

Sample data and code here;

```
EmpID       EmpName    EmpSalary            ManagerID
----------- ---------- -------------------- -----------
1           Neevan     100000               6
2           Mukesh     30000                6
3           Disha      50000                6
4           Martin     90000                6
5           Roy        170000               6
6           Anvesh     168000               NULL



CREATE TABLE empsalary
(
    EmpID INT
    ,EmpName VARCHAR(10)
    ,EmpSalary BIGINT
    ,ManagerID INT 
)

INSERT INTO empsalary
VALUES
(1,'Neevan',100000,6)
,(2,'Mukesh',30000,6)
,(3,'Disha',50000,6)
,(4,'Martin',90000,6)
,(5,'Roy',170000,6)
,(6,'Anvesh',168000,NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your correlations are all backwards.  The right way is:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM empsalary e
WHERE e.empsalary > (SELECT m.empsalary 
                     FROM empsalary  m
                     WHERE m.EmpID = e.ManagerID 
                    );
```

Notice that I have used the `m` table alias for the manager record.  This helps to follow the logic.

Comment: techically right, but your logical explanation for correlation is not enough for me..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for me to re-write how to do it, as Gordon has done a good enough job already, but I can explain why yours returned null...

For me to answer this, I needed to re-write yours slightly to help me to read it. It is essentially the same as yours. Also, similarly to how Gordon has done, I've substituted e for m and e1 for e. I've also called your tables tblSalaries, so that the table names aren't the same as the column name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblSalaries as m
WHERE m.empsalary=(
                   SELECT e.empsalary 
                   FROM tblSalaries as e 
                   WHERE e.ManagerID = m.EmpID
                   AND e.EmpSalary > m e.EmpSalary)
```

If we work backwards and interpret the last part firstly:

```
...
(
 SELECT e.empsalary 
 FROM tblSalaries as e 
 WHERE e.ManagerID = m.EmpID
 AND e.EmpSalary > m.EmpSalary)
```

Firstly, `WHERE m.ManagerID = e.EmpI`D is saying 'Find all employees in e who's manager ID is the same as the employee ID in m'. Considering there is only one managerID (6), then records 1-5 from e will all match the manager record, on m (6) on this.

Your next clause `AND e.EmpSalary > m.EmpSalary` is finding those who's salary is greater than the managers'. Therefore, you are left with record 5 (Roy) as you intended.

Now to return to your main query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tblSalaries as m
    WHERE m.empsalary= (...tblSalaries as e...)
```

We have established that table e in the brackets has returned Roy, but we have also established that it only matches records in table m, where m is a manager. Ultimately, you are asking then to find where the manager's salary = Roy's salary; the answer, `null`.

Comment: ,(5,'Roy',170000,6)
,(6,'Anvesh',168000,NULL) their Id's are equal (6=6) and 170000>168000  and Im searching this id's salary but it results null why I can't understand..

Comment: Yes, but their salaries aren't - and that is the 'Where Clause' you are using. Using your aliases, your table e only returns the manager (6,'Anvesh',168000,NULL)  and the table e1 only returns Roy (5,'Roy',170000,6). You are then asking in this part `WHERE e.empsalary=` to select all where the manager's salary = Roy's salary, which is null. Try changing Roy's salary to match the manager's. You'll find that it then brings back the manager.